# PG::Error: ERROR: function left(character varying, integer) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, substring, postgresql-9.1

I'm using PostgreSQL along with Rails 3.2. One of my db migrations has the following:

```
execute <<-SQL
  CREATE INDEX users_multi_idx
  ON users (lower(left(fname, 1)), fname)
  WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
SQL
```

While migrating on some dbs, we're getting the following error:

```
==  AddFnameIndexToUsers: migrating ===========================================
-- execute("      CREATE INDEX users_multi_idx\n      ON users (lower(left(fname, 1)), fname)\n      WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;\n")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  function left(character varying, integer) does not exist
LINE 2:       ON users (lower(left(fname, 1)), fname)
                              ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
:       CREATE INDEX users_multi_idx
      ON users (lower(left(fname, 1)), fname)
      WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
```

What's strange is this does not happen on all dbs, just some (staging). Any suggestions as to what's wrong with this index execution?

Answer (score 10):

You tagged it [postgresql-9.1](/questions/tagged/postgresql-9.1), but I strongly suspect you are dealing with an older version here. You can check which version you're using by asking:

```
SELECT version();
```

[`left()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) was introduced with version 9.1. If you are using an older version, substitute `left(fname, 1)` with:

```
substr(fname, 1, 1)
```

If you cannot modify the query for some reason ([like @Wize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33819367/939860)), you can create a drop-in replacement for older versions before 9.1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.left(text, int)
 RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql STABLE COST 30 AS
'SELECT substr($1, 1, $2)';
```

This typically *won't* cause conflicts after a version upgrade, since the default [schema search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777) has `pg_catalog` (implicitly) before `public`, so the user-defined function is out of business as soon as the system function exits - unless schema-qualified explicitly. But you should remove it after a version upgrade anyway.

I added this, to suggest a number of improvements over what @Wize provided:

- Use `LANGUAGE sql` (not `plpgsql`) for multiple reasons:

  - Shorter, simpler.
  - [plpgsql is not installed by default in versions before 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-overview.html), so you might run into another problem just like the one you are trying to solve.
  - The simple function I present can be [inlined](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions), which improves performance in the context of bigger queries.
- Use function volatility `STABLE`, that's appropriate and helps performance.
- Use `$n` notation to reference function parameters, since parameter names are not supported for SQL functions in older versions.
- Create the function in the `public` schema explicitly. Else it might be created in the current users "private" schema and not work for other users. Depending on your [schema search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777), this should serve you best.
- Use data type `text`, which is the default character type and the same as `left()` or `substr()` return. Works for `varchar` as well.

Comment: Thank you Erwin, that was the issue we had members using different versions of postgres

Answer (score 2):

Just create the following function for versions of Posgres before 9.1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION left(s character varying,i int)
RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  return substr(s, 1, i);
 END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: I provided this answer, because I wasnt able to change the code inside library. So this may help others in a similar situation

Comment: This is useful, but I see room for improvement. You might be interested in the alternative I added to my answer.

Comment: Does anyone know why I was getting ERROR: syntax error at or near "COST" why creating this function? It went go if I removed VOLATILE COST 100;